# Two light switches do not work

Tags: switch

I recently changed a timer out in 3 switch "bank". In changing out the timer I accidently touched the Common from the timer to another light switch. It short circuited. Since that time the timer works fine but the other two switches in the "bank" do not work. I have checked the breaker and it DID NOT trip. Di9d I burn something out in the wall? And is there danger of fire. I changed out the switch that was touched by the Common still nothing> Thanks for any help.

Comment: How many "hot" wires do you have in the switch box? Generally there should be 1 incoming hot wire to the switch box. It's then brached out to the switches in the box. The only time that you'll find more than one hot wire is if 2 or more circuits "happen" to share the same switch box ( ie; inside light and outside light ). You're timer switch working now indicates multiple hot wires.

Comment: Do any of these switches use "backstab" connections instead of the screws?

Comment: Not to address your question, but, you should never be working on live wiring. Always turn off the breaker and verify that all wires are cold using a non-contact voltage tester.

Answer (score 3):

Some tripped breakers do not appear tripped - they don't flip all the way to OFF. Try flipping off and then back on again all breakers you think might be the one.

Comment: I despise breakers without a trip indicator... To add to @TomCarpenters answer... Instead of flipping every breaker off, push its switch towards the center of your breaker box. If it's tripped, even unnoticed by your eye, the switch will have a little bit of travel. Breakers that aren't tripped won't have any travel.